# Android Independent viewModel for recyclerView's adapter

Tags: android, mvvm, android-recyclerview, viewmodel, android-databinding

We have a problem in mvvm design pattern with recyclerView:
We have a fragment with own view model (FragmentViewModel)
and a list adapter with it's own view model (ListViewModel)

**the problems are these:**

- Inside our fragment's view model(FragmentViewModel), we get our data from api repository,How to set these values to our adapter's view model(ListViewModel)?
- Inside of adapter's view model(ListViewModel),when row item clicked, How to call a function inside our fragments's view model(FragmentViewModel) to do something with fragment's view?

**Notes:**
- We use dagger to inject our viewModels and adapter.
- Our list adapter will reuse with other fragments.

Comment: This is just my opinion but.... Creating a ViewModel for an adapter is over engineering. The purpose of an adapter is to display your data in a list, it shouldn't contain any business logic of any kind as per the Single Responsibility Principle.

Comment: there is no logic inside out adapter viewModel, we just pass data to this view model

Comment: So just pass the data directly to the adapter?

Comment: yes but adapter should inject with it's dependency(viewModel)

Answer (score 0):

My suggestion would be, /n
Never use Fragment own's ViewModel, instead used activity one with a key. which differentiate between different fragment.

```
ViewModelProviders.of(requireActivity(), factory).get(detail.getJobId(), TimelineActivityViewModel.class);
```

here `detail.getJobId()` is an ID.

Comment: What is the reason for your suggestion?